# Installation error for Spring IDE in Eclipse Mars using the Eclipse market place or the install new software option

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spring-ide

I have Eclipse Java EE IDE Version: Mars Release (4.5.0),Build id: 20150621-1200. I want to install latest Spring IDE. Tried to install it from the Eclipse Marketplace option. After clicking install it shows a very slow progress bar of calculating requirements and dependencies. After sometime it shows the error message below (**"cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions."**). But after completing that it does not install any of it.

[image]

I have also tried from Install new software option with this url: "http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.5/" . But it results in same error.

Also tried downloading STS (Spring tool suit ) and copying the plugin and features folder in the root eclipse directory. Yet nothing seems to work. So I am kind of stuck here.

Can anyone guide me what am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the details of the error; it will tell us exactly what is blocking the installation.

Comment: Why don't you simply download STS directly from [Spring's site](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all) and install it? The newest version is based on Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2).

Comment: FYI for 2018 installs or later - you need to install STS 3 to get the spring perspective and most of the Spring items installed in the new menu.  In addition to ensuring everything installs properly.  If you installed STS 4 first, you can just install STS 3 plug-in as well from the Marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue but resolved by following below steps:
1) Goto Eclipse -> help -> check for updates[wait until all update process is over]
2) then try installing spring IDE from eclipse market place

Comment: Also, you may need to go into the marketplace and find your already installed STS 3/4 plugins, and click on the "installed" button, which will bring up a dialog where you can check for or install pending upgrades...